# flycheck cannot use gfortran, executable not found

Tags: osx, flycheck, fortran

Previously I had been able to use flycheck for fortran files, but something seems to have broken perhaps during an update.

```
Mac OSX catalina (latest)
gfortran 9.3.0 from homebrew
emacs 26.3 from homebrew
```

When I call `flycheck-select-checker` and then select `fortran-gfortran` I get the following error buffer:

```
Syntax checker in buffer test.f90 in f90-mode:

  fortran-gfortran (disabled)
    - major mode: `f90-mode' supported
    - may enable: Automatically disabled!
    - executable: Not found

Flycheck cannot use this syntax checker for this buffer.

Flycheck Mode is enabled.  Use M-x universal-argument C-c ! x to enable disabled
checkers.

--------------------

Flycheck version: 32snapshot (package: 20191108.2129)
Emacs version:    26.3
System:           x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0
Window system:    ns
```

perhaps relevant is that it cannot find gfortran from within a shell inside emacs, but it is available from a regular mac osx terminal

Comment: Make sure `fortran-gfortran` is in your `exec-path`. You can check your `exec-path` with `C-h v exec-path`. Or, explicitly set somewhere in your init `flycheck-fortran-gfortran-executable` to point to the executable.

Comment: that was the problem, and in fact I had another problem where pyvenv-activate was overwriting my exec-path changes

Comment: @caisah - please make your comment an answer! The OP should then accept it, since  it solves his problem.

Comment: I have added the comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `fortran-gfortran` is in your `exec-path`. (You can check your `exec-path` with <kbd>C-h v exec-path</kbd>.)

Or, explicitly set somewhere in your init `flycheck-fortran-gfortran-executable` to point to the executable.

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me.
I have Emacs on Windows and Flycheck could not find
the executable for my c/c++-gcc checker.

I have added:

```
(setq flycheck-c/c++-gcc-executable "D:\\StandaloneApps\\strawberry\\c\\bin\\gcc.exe")
```

in my `init.el` file, and now .. Flycheck works in C/C++ mode.

( now, you can guess that I point to the `gcc.exe` packaged with perl :) ;) ;D )

Comment: Those double backslashes are pretty hideous, IMO.  Emacs will generally be happier if you use forward slashes instead.